# Derivative of Projection on Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f \colon X \times Y\to X $ be the projection map, where $X$ and $Y$ are manifolds. I need to show that the derivative on tangent spaces $$Df(x,y) \colon T_x(X) \times T_y(Y)\to T_x(X)$$ will also be the analogous projection.

I am not sure how to start, as I am new to the subject.

As suggested in the comments, this I think is the required isomorphism
$D\phi_0×D\psi_0 \to (D\phi_0,D\psi_0)$, where $\phi,\psi$ are local parametrizations of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: It seems that you already know $T_{(x,y)}(X \times Y) \approx T_x(X) \times T_y(Y)$. Can you explictly describe how this isomorphism looks like?

Comment: Yes, I can use the product map of Derivative of parametrizations @PaulFrost

Comment: Can you edit our question and *explicitly write down* an isomorphism $\phi : T_x(X) \times T_y(Y) \to T_{(x,y)}(X \times Y)$?

Comment: Is this the one, actually it's inverse?@PaulFrost

Comment: No matter, you can also write down $\psi : T_{(x,y)}(X \times Y) \to T_x(X) \times T_y(Y)$.

Comment: You should explain more precisely  how the isomorphism looks like. The reason why I am insistent on this point is that readers have to know which definition of a *tangent vector*  you use (there are various alternative approaches). It seems to be related to "local parametrizations" (a synonym for  "chart" in an atlas?). What are $\phi_0, \psi_0$ and their differentials $D\phi_0, D\psi_0$?

Comment: Yeah.. exactly  $\phi,\psi$ are local parametrizations and $D\phi_0$ is the Derivative of $\phi$ at 0 @PaulFrost

Comment: as suggested above, you should indicate which definition of tangent space you're working with and explicitly write down the rules for the functions. The reason paul (rightfully) insists on this is because like he said, there are several equivalent ways of defining tangent spaces, and in some formulations, this statement is almost trivial (a 2 line proof). So, to get a directly helpful, you should edit the question to EXPLICITLY write down the isomorphism (and it would also be good to explain your notation, even if it is standard notation, just so you get direct answers)

Comment: also, write down what you know/ how much you know, so that in the answers, we do not assume more than you already know/ assume you do not know certain things and then spend a long time explaining basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always start with what you know:

1. As $X$ and $Y$ are manifolds, they are equipped with local coordinates $x_i$, $y_i$
2. As a product manifold, $X\times Y$ has a local coordinate system that looks like $(x_i, y_i)$
3. The projection map $f(x,y) = x$

So now, the exercise becomes: write down the differential of the projection in the $(x_i,y_i)$ coordinate system. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I am not that much familiar with concept of coordinates as my text uses local parametrizations @Neal

Comment: If $\phi\colon U\to X$, $U\subset\Bbb R^n$ open, is a parametrization, then $\phi^{-1}$ defines local coordinates on $\phi(U)$.